# Why does this continue to print 9

Tags: javascript

```js
function final(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
  while (param2 <= param3) {
    if (param2 % param1 === 0) {
      console.log(param2);
    } else if (param2 % param1 === param4) {
      break;
    }
    param2++;
  }
}

final(3, 5, 17, 9);
```

I'm struggling here a bit, essentially if the multiple of `param2` and `param1` is equal to `param4`, you're supposed to ignore it. Yet this continues to print out `9`? What's wrong with my code? I can't figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: `if the multiple of param2 and param1 is equal to param4` Multiple? But you're using `param2 % param1 === param4`, `%` is modulo, not multiplication?

Comment: `X % 3` can never be `9`. The value of `X % 3` will be one of `0`, `1`, or `2`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm supposed to print the "multiples of param1, starting at param2, extending to param3, but ignoring the multiple if it equals param4". So based on this reading, I'm thinking modulus.

Comment: I get the correct output here right now, almost... it prints out 15,12,9,6... the only problem is the 9.

Comment: Your order is wrong (you're checking the second condition first) and your second condition is wrong (there shouldn't be a `% param1`) and your second body is wrong (there shouldn't be a `break;`).

Comment: “ignoring the multiple if it equals param4”, which conditional matches that case? Perhaps you need another one. Also, I would suggest you try to use better, more descriptive variable names, it may help you troubleshoot better.

Comment: it actually outputs 6,9,12,15 ... in that order ... try checking to make sure param2 !== param4

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `param2 % param1` will anyway be `0` when param4 is `9`.

You can see the difference from another point of view, if you change code logic a little:

```
function final(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
  for (var loop = param2; loop <= param3; loop++) {
    if (loop % param1 === 0) {
      if (loop === param4) continue;
      console.log(loop);
    }
  }
}

final(3, 5, 17, 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you should ignore if param2 === param4.

```js
    function final(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
      while (param2 <= param3) { 
        if (param2 % param1 === 0 && param2 !== param4) {
           console.log(param2)
        } else if (param2 % param1 === param4) {
          break;
        }
        param2++;
      }
    }

    final(3, 5, 17, 9);
```

Comment: What is that `if (param2 % param1 === param4)` part for?

Comment: I have no clue. That part only the OP would know if it serves any purpose.